# Skipping user input

Tags: perl

I am using:

```
use Term::Prompt;
use Term::ReadKey;
```

I have my user input section:

```
my $value1 = prompt( 'n', 'Enter num1: ', '', '' );
my $value2 = prompt( 'x', 'Enter name1: ', '', '' );
my $value3 = prompt( 'n', 'Enter num2: ', '', '' );
my $value4 = prompt( 'n', 'Enter num3: ', '', '' );
my $value5 = prompt( 'x', 'Enter name2: ', '', '' );
```

Here is my query:

```
SELECT data1, data2, data3
           FROM Table1
          WHERE value1 = '$value1'
 AND NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT NULL
           FROM Table2
          WHERE value2 = '$value2')
 AND NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT NULL
           FROM Table3
          WHERE value3 = '$value3')
 AND NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT NULL
           FROM Table4
          WHERE value4 = '$value4')
```

I am trying to use a 'keypress' like <kbd>enter</kbd> or <kbd>esc</kbd> to skip the input and use a default value instead, without using the default setting in the prompt, because I don't want the user to see the default.

If that wasn't clear, I hope this is.

So, for prompt 3 and 4, I would like the user to just hit the <kbd>enter</kbd> key, and have the prompt use a default value instead and skip the prompt.

-OR-

Is there a better way to do this, as some prompts aren't needed in the query?

Comment: (1) You could have a 'shown-to-the-user' default such as `N/A` that is different from the default used in the code; (2) you should probably not include in the query those portions that aren't needed (so, if there isn't a value for `$value4`, you omit the `AND NOT EXISTS(…= '$value4')` section of the query).

Answer (score 0):

Since your defaults are '' they will evaluate as false so use the logical-or operator '||' like this:

```
 my @defaults = ( ... a list of default values ... );

 my $value1 = prompt( 'n', 'Enter num1: ',  '', '' ) || $defaults[1];
 my $value2 = prompt( 'x', 'Enter name1: ', '', '' ) || $defaults[2];
 my $value3 = prompt( 'n', 'Enter num2: ',  '', '' ) || $defaults[3];
 my $value4 = prompt( 'n', 'Enter num3: ',  '', '' ) || $defaults[4];
 my $value5 = prompt( 'x', 'Enter name2: ', '', '' ) || $defaults[5];
```

if the prompt returns the default empty string, it will evaluate the right side of the OR and return your desired default.